# Hide the noData line on rich:extendedDataTable

Tags: jsf, richfaces, jsf-1.2

I'm using jsf 1.2 with richfaces 3.3.3 to maintain an old java project and I have to hide the "No Data" line when the list passed to my rich:extendedDataTable is empty.

I'm aware of the "noDataLabel" property, but it only makes possible to change the label of the line. I've tried to leave it blank but then it comes with the "No Data" standard message.

How do I hide it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The table row has class `extdt-noData-row`, you can overwrite it to make hidden.